# how to pass value from Datagridview to combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have **Datagridview** and **combobox**.
**I need to send data from Datagridview to combobox** (I need that for update that data and return it back to Datagridview).

I'm using this code in **DoubleClick** event of Datagridview to get data from datagridview to combobox and another textbox and DateTimepicker:

```
private void mgrid_searchClient_Contrat_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mcb_NomClient.Text= this.mgrid_searchClient_Contrat.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    mtb_NomContrat.Text = this.mgrid_searchClient_Contrat.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    mdtp_DATEECHIANCE.Text = this.mgrid_searchClient_Contrat.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();    
}
```

`mcb_NomClient` is a ComboBox , `mtb_NomContrat` is a TextBox, and `mdtp_DATEECHIANCE` is DateTimePicker.

Comment: You forgot to write the question and / or to describe the problem

Comment: Double-click event of what? And yes, you forgot the question.

Comment: The problem is how to make that value in datagridview show up in combobox after I double-click on the cell in datagridview.

Comment: @Sach Double-click of datagridview.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: i get datagrideview cell data that i select and doucleclick on it data in textbox and DateTimePicker but i get nothing in combobox not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the double-clicked cell content to the `ComboBox`, you may use `DataGridView.CurrentCell.Value`, and `ComboBox.Items.Add()` as follows.

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var val = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(val);
}
```

Doing so will only 'add' an item, but to show an item in the `ComboBox` you'll need to set the `SelectedIndex` as well.

To show the most-recently added item:

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var val = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(val);
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

To show the first item:

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var val = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(val);
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT (due to OP's updated requirements):**

Let's say your `DataGridView` has 3 columns, namely, `ID`, `Name`, and `City`. And let us also say your `ComboBox` is populated with those `Name` values. And upon double-clicking a `DataGridView` row (any cell in a particular row), you want to *display* in the `ComboBox` the `Name` value that matches the double-clicked row's `Name`.

For example; DGV looks like this:

> ID | Name | City
>
> ---
>
> 1 | Jane | New York
>
> 2 | Tom | Melbourne
>
> 3 | Chelsea | London

And your `ComboBox` has values `Jane`, `Tom`, and `Chelsea`. When you double click a row (any cell), you want to show that row's name. For instance, you double-click the cell `London` and you want the `ComboBox` to show `Chelsea`.

In that case you need to get the current row (clicked row), then get the `Name` column value in that row, and look it up in the `ComboBox` values.

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
    var selectedName = currentRow.Cells[1].Value;

    var index = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(selectedName.ToString());
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to add new item in combobox because it already has items from another source. i just want to show the exact item that in cell and view it on combobox.

Comment: i have tryed `comboBox1.Items.Add()` but it adds another item who is already exist.

Comment: Well, that's why we asked you to clearly define your question first, which you didn't. So what are the items that are in the ComboBox? Is it values from a particular column in DataGridView, or are ALL cell content from DGV in the ComboBox? What you ask for can be done easily but you should define your problem more clearly. Please show an example of data in your DGV, what you have in ComboBox, and upon clicking what you expect to happen.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not good in English that's why i didn't ask well. i will clear that step by step here:
1/ it's all about add and update information in one form. 
2/ combobox is getting datat from table called Clients. so it's show clients name.

Comment: `3/ datagridview is getting data from table called Contrat whom is contained column called clienname and 2 others called contraname and datecontrat. 
4/ when i want to update client i have to find that client in datagrid and select it with doubleclick to view that client name in combobx. not to add him to combobox as 'comboBox1.Items.Add()' do.

Comment: - so it's all about send value from datagrid to combobox who already exist in combobox to chose another one and update it to datagrid again .

Comment: yes yes after you edit the answer that's what i want exactly now you get what i want 100%

Comment: i am using full selected cell so when i click on the cell it's get the name of client that's all.